# Coroutine Worker gets killed after kill the app

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, android-workmanager

Lets say that i have an activity that starts a worker. inside the worker i do a pseudo suspend proccess and then i print out a result from the database. Here is the code

The activity which starts the worker is

```
class SplashActivity: BaseActivity() {
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)
    
    
        val oneTimeRequest = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker::class.java).setInputData(Data.Builder().apply {
            putInt("data", 1)
        }.build()).addTag("worktag").build()
        WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext).enqueue(oneTimeRequest)
        
        
    }
}
```

The worker is the below

```
class MyWorker @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted private val appContext: Context,
    @Assisted private val params: WorkerParameters,
    private val serverRepository: ServerRepository
) : CoroutineWorker(appContext, params) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        
        GlobalScope.launch {
            for (i in 0..10) {
                println("$i")
                delay(1000)
            }
    
            val servers = serverRepository.getServers()
            runOnUiThread {
                Toast.makeText(appContext, "${servers.firstOrNull()?.serverAddress}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        
        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

So the result is that i see in the logcat the system.out with 1,2,3... and then i see a toast messages.
However, when i totally kill the app from the recent while the counter still counts, i never see the toast message.
Why is this happening since i have a GlobalScope coroutine?
And what is the right way to do this??

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If you kill the app, you should not expect anything else to happen. If it's killed, it's killed. Nothing happening within your application can outlive the application.

Comment: Use foreground service and execute your operation inside service. So that even if your app killed it still execute your logic

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to achieve a similar goal. I managed my work by using ForegroundService.
You can find more here
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services

Comment: Can you please share a small example code in order to understand what you did? Thank you